# Double/Float TO Rational (X/Y Form)

Tags: c++

I applied the following method to convert Double/Float form to rational form.

For Ex.

```
a=0.125
Find t=1000 
Find k=GCD(t,a*t);
Print (a*t/k) "/" t/k
```

It gives correct o/p for 0.125 but not with 0.12.
The problem lies in finding the t.Please help me out in this.
Here is the code,

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int gcd(int a,int b)
{
  if(b==0)
  return a;
  else
  return gcd(b,a%b);
}
void DoubleToRational(float a)
{
  int t=1;
  while((float)t*a!=(int)(t*a))
  {
   //cout<<t*a<<" "<<(float)t*a<<" "<<(int)(t*a)<<endl; // For Checking
   t=t*10;
  }
  int k=gcd(t*a,t);
  cout<<(int)t*a/k<<" / "<<t/k;
}
int main()
{
  DoubleToRational(0.125); //0.021 seconds Works Perfectly
 // DoubleToRational(0.12); //Didnt Work ????
  return 0;
}
```

**Also I don't expect this method to work efficiently when the precision is large.
Please suggest the modifications/other method in that case.**

Answer (score 4):

The number `0.125` can be represented exactly in binary floating point. But the number `0.12` cannot. So you are finding the rational value of the nearest representable number to `0.12`. Which is most definitely not `3/25`. In fact the [closest double precision value](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=0.12) to `0.12` is:

```
0.11999 99999 99999 99555 91079 01499 37383 83054 73327 63671 875
```

To make any reasonable headway with this task you will probably need to represent your values with a decimal data type rather than a binary type like `double`.

If the above doesn't make any real sense to you then I suggest you have a good read of: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Use a decimal representation for 0.12 rather than binary. Stop using `double`.

Comment: But suppose if the input is given in double
like 0.12,2.3456,1.76899922 etc then what method should i apply to make it to x/y form....

Comment: You can't represent `0.12` in a `double`, like I said. The closest you can get is `0.11999 99999 99999 99555 91079 01499 37383 83054 73327 63671 875`. So if you start from a `double`, it's too late. You've lost the important information. You need to use a decimal representation. Read the paper I linked to.

Comment: ok thanks for clearing my doubts...
also i would like to know another method when the prcecision is high.....